# How to report 1099 Misc income while working for a different employer

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1099-misc

I was in a company A, which got acquired in 2012. All the stocks I owned were vested immediately and 10% of the amount was kept by the acquiring company for 18 months. I left the company and joined company B in 2013.

I got a payment via cheque from a bank (escrow) in 2014. Also, I received a form 1099-MISC for the same.

Now, when I tried filing my taxes using a tax software, I get stuck because there is no option to select which case applies to me. There are options which say this income was to be on a W-2 but is not and the employee is employed with that company (But I am in company B now).

It is very confusing but none of these directly make sense for my case. It also looks like that 1099-MISC is for contractors but not for permanent employees.

Sorry for being a bit ambiguous, I can get exact choices later from the software, but if you have any suggestions based on information I gave so far, then please advise.

Thanks a lot!

Gaurav

Comment: In HRBlock/TaxCut, there is a "Show Box" menu that lets you jump directly to each form that you have received in the mail. Is 1099-MISC listed there?

Comment: I am using turbotax, I was not able to find show box, also, i did receive this 1099-MISC in mail. 1099 MISC shows the income in item number 7, i.e. non-employee compensation.

Comment: Also, do I need to file form SS-8? I am too confused right now.

Comment: I meant "shoe box" sorry. I have no idea for TurboTax nor SS-8, sorry.

Comment: Turbotax has four tiers of software for increasing complexity of return.  I don't know what their lowest tier covers.  You may need to get a more expensive version.